# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit fails to boot when I installed ubuntu kernel 4.13.0.26. What do I do?

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, kernel, update-manager

Update Manager offered me to install kernel 4.13.0.26 as the part of new security update. I installed it and it asked me to reboot my system. When I rebooted my system, GRUB offered me an option to select Ubuntu, Advanced Options for Ubuntu and some memtests. When I select Ubuntu, it fails to boot at all and restarts my computer. When I choose to boot my previous kernel 4.10.0.42, it starts normally? Should I still use 4.10.0.42 or try to update 4.13.0.26? How to fix this error?

Thankful in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there have been booting issues with the update, but then it seems like the latest update fixes it (there's an official bug report at launchpad, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742323)).

Try removing the non-booting kernel (refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)) and re-updating your kernel to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I have removed the non-booting kernel. Can you, please, explain to me how to update my kernel to the latest version?

Comment: `sudo apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade` : Check the kernel version that shows up in the "Packages to be installed" list, double confirm that it is newer than the non-booting version.

Comment: It doesn't show any kernel version.

Comment: Then check from this command: `apt-cache policy linux-image`. The `candidate` line would show you which kernel would be installed.

Comment: It says nothing in the candidate line

Comment: Or `apt-cache madison linux-image*` ?

Comment: This command does nothing.

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885820/how-to-check-the-version-before-install-packages-using-apt-get